# Function inside let not Num

Tags: haskell, tree, let

I have these

```
data Fruit = Peach | Apple | Pear | Lemon | Fig deriving (Show,Eq)
data FTree = Bud | Split FTree FTree | Flat Fruit FTree deriving (Show,Eq)
```

and this meant to count the number of occurrences of an inputted fruit type

```
ftreeFOccurs cft ft =
  let ftFO Bud = 0
      ftFO (Flat frt ft) = if (frt == cft) then (1 + (ftFO ft)) else (ftFO ft)
      ftFO (Split ft1 ft2) = (Split (ftFO ft1) (ftFO ft2))
  in ftFO ft
```

and here would be a typical tree

```
Split (Split Bud Bud) (Flat Fig (Flat Lemon (Flat Apple Bud)))
```

But when I submit `ftreeFOccurs` I get this error

```
No instance for (Num FTree) arising from the literal `0'
    * In the expression: 0
      In an equation for `ftFO': ftFO Bud = 0
```

A similar function, however,

```
ftreeHeight Bud = 0
ftreeHeight (Flat frt ft) = 1 + ftreeHeight ft
ftreeHeight (Split ft1 ft2) = deeper (1 + ftreeHeight ft1) (1 + ftreeHeight ft2)
                              where deeper t1 t2 = if (t1 >= t2) then t1 else t2
```

works. This is a translation of an SML problem from *The Little MLer*, where the `occurs` function has a 2-tuple parameter with the fruit and the tree carried through the recursions ... which doesn't seem like the Haskell way. But then I'm not sure why having a function in a `let` makes this difference.

Comment: Add `ftFO :: FTree -> Int` to your `let` block and see if the new errors are more immediately obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put some types on your functions so that Haskell can give you better hints about where you went wrong. Without types, it will make assumptions about what you meant until it reaches a contradiction, and you won't know which assumption was wrong.

In this case, the confusion is that sometimes `ftFO` returns a number, and sometimes it returns an `FTree`. This isn't want you meant, but it's technically allowed if Haskell assumes that `FTree` can be understood as a number. So Haskell carries on with that idea for a while until it discovers that nobody has said how to interpret `FTree` as a number.

Comment: That makes sense, but simply adding `deriving Num` doesn't work. I see the problem is that last line where I'm trying to just send the `Split` match on through to the next level. How else could I cycle through like I'm trying to do in the last line and not run afoul of the counting?

Comment: The last case should return the sum of two recursive calls if you're trying to count the total number of occurrences.

Comment: Much better would be `ftFO (Split ft1 ft2) = ftFO ft1 + ftFO ft2`. Right...

Answer (score 2):

My mistake, as has been pointed out, is not realizing the third pattern,

```
....
ftFO (Split ft1 ft2) = (Split (ftFO ft1) (ftFO ft2))
....
```

is of type `FTree` while the goal of the function is to produce an integer answer. This correction works

```
ftreeFOccurs2 cft ft =
  let ftFO :: FTree -> Int
      ftFO Bud = 0
      ftFO (Flat frt ft) = if (frt == cft) then (1 + (ftFO ft)) else (ftFO ft)
      ftFO (Split ft1 ft2) = ftFO ft1 + ftFO ft2
  in ftFO ft
```

As was also pointed out, including the hoped-for type declaration in the `let` made the error message much more understandable.